# logstash charset error (gelf)

Tags: logging, logstash, docker-compose, elk

I had some trouble with Logstash and Nginx (all running on Docker).
On my docker-compose file i was trying to enable logging from Nginx container to Logstash:

```
nginx:
container_name: nginx
image: nginx:latest
volumes:
  - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  - ./nginx/.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/.htpasswd
  - ./nginx/sites-enabled/:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
ports:
  - "80:80"
logging:
  driver: "gelf"
  options:
    gelf-address: "udp://127.0.0.1:5001"
depends_on:
  - kibana
networks:
  - elk
```

And this is my logstash.conf:

```
input {
    udp {
    port => 5001
    type => "nginx"
    codec => plain {
       charset => "ISO-8859-1"
     }
  }
}
```

Everthing working, but on Kibana i'am get something like this:

```
type:nginx message:ÿÀmkÜ8à¿"æSÂùEc½ØR>áH n¡¥u1³òÈ+bËÁvÒ¥¥ÿ½ÏoøämOkX!pY÷<DúØòçº½¯÷PÀ~Y·cXxßibð®©ÐvÊÊ:QHû!¾K[¿ÐV7GãÆ£ÿH)åÑÃÃ'QÓ¸ÓH»x<^k¬°¡¥VÊD/ë¯4ÏTJ¯wâ9å«¸vv°úVüûþ>ó>?¥£6ª­7O§çBÌéÅ·õVÜ_¶uáºm*Y)ÛØ Ñÿ)Òj£ÚJÙDePÀÞZÞÁ£1Øu¦U®BWÀÌ<·a]Ê#xÈSÊWQNb$^Ö,Öï !¬ù yÒ¢n£4F`¢µ­g©Ï(£±ÎÆrp5SÝYÇHf®qPÀÖ|PÊ¼ yJù ac:xDWJUJ{Bã±õª­°UÒ:¥ô7(`HM<¤<ìjõ]pôm+ ¤Q«æÌMÛ]`dkñJ6VvRéHFíI«è !-4ñiað§¯~¦÷ ÀCÔ-bÆèàÏßÿÿ=¬bp host:172.18.0.1 @version:1 @timestamp:March 6th 2019, 18:22:19.191 _id:OyeZU2kBwNJDhqLcJRYd _type:doc _index:nginx _score: -
```

Any ideas?
p.s. Sorry for my terrible English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, problem solved by editing logstash.conf and replace "udp" section to "gelf" section.